# When is a completely normal and Hausdorf topology orderable?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

From here, I find that all order topologies are completely normal and Hausdorf, but does being completely normal and Hausdorf imply that the topology can be derived from an order? If not, what more criteria are required for two way?

Comment: From the [Wikipedia article on normal spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space), we may find that every metric space is completely normal Hausdorff (actually perfectly normal Hausdorff, which is strictly stronger), but not all metric spaces have their topology induced by an order.

Comment: Sorgenfrey is a name that opens many doors. Then again, what about $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: On $\pi$-base https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=completely%20normal%20%2B%20t_2%20%2B%20~lots you can find examples of completely normal Hausdorff spaces that aren't Linearly Ordered Topological Spaces (LOTS). I invite you to check because sometimes pi base has mistakes. In *Thron, W. J., and Susan J. Zimmerman. “A Characterization of Order Topologies by Means of Minimal T0-Topologies.” Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 27, no. 1, 1971, pp. 161–67.* https://doi.org/10.2307/2037281 you can find a topological characterization of LOTS, though it might not be too useful.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thank u

Comment: @Sassatelli and others please let us know at https://github.com/pi-base/data/issues when those mistakes are found! :-)

Comment: @StevenClontz Yeah, I don't remember, it was years ago.

Comment: As others mentioned, completely normal Hausdorff is light years away from orderable. In addition to the very generic characterization mentioned above, there are quite useful ones for connected spaces (see [here](http://at.yorku.ca/t/a/i/c/18.htm) for an overview, or [here](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/13258) for a quite comprehensive paper). Also in case of zero-dimensional spaces there exist very reasonable characterizations, see the overview paper mentioned above.

Comment: If $X$ is orderable then $X - x$ cannot be connected except possibly if $x = \min X$ or $x = \max X$. This provides many counterexamples, for instance $\mathbf{R}^n$ for $n > 1$.